# MySQL PhP copy from column 1 and insert into column 2 but keep both values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello so i basically made this little php code below to display the product name in `<h2>` tags and the product `$manufacture` inside the description on the top and bottom of the product page,but it turns out that for 20.000 products this is very CPU usage intensive.

```
   <div id="description">
        <h2><?= $heading_title; ?></h2><?php echo $description; ?> 
          <center>
            <li style="list-style-type:none;">
            You can also visit us at : <a href=<?="$manufacturers"?>><?= $manufacturer?></a>
            </li>
          </center>
    </div>
```

So i am trying something new but i can't quite put my finger around it.

I'm trying to do a mass MySQL php script that will auto generate all the names from column name before all the column description in the database i'm just not sure how to start

only thing i have is this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (description) VALUES (name)";
```

not sure if this will work eveen if it does wont it just import all names into description i kinda need for every product to insert its own name into the description

**UPDATE**

let's say i have 1 products

name : Iphone || description : Worst phone ever

after update

name : Iphone || description : Iphone Worst phone ever

where the table name is `Prodcut` Column 1 is `name` column 2 is `description`

I also tried this

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET description = name";
```

Which just copies the value of 1 column and replaces the value of the other column

Comment: it will be extremely useful if you provide some sample data before modification and your expected output after modification

Comment: how is that query constructed? because it is a strange thing that the CPU usage is so intensive for just 20k products... maybe you have missing keys in db?

Comment: Guys the first code at the very top just generated the name and manufacturer at the top and bottom of the description and for every 1 click on a page the code got executed and created alot of CPU usage i am just trying to make it all in 1 in the database

Comment: If you want your database to do this work, you can use the CONCAT approach from your answer when you are selecting the records to display rather than updating all your records with redundant information. If you are needing to improve performance, have you considered pagination rather than displaying all 20000 records at once?

Comment: I didn't have performance issues ,everything was runing fast and without a problem,just my CPU usage(in the hosting) went up to roof because of that php script ,hence it was generated everytime someone clicked on a product as far as the pagination i dont have all 20.000 product displayed at once they are 12 per page or so.Even though i don't understand how that php script eats up the CPU time hence the whole stupid site is based on php shouldnt everything do that.it just displayed the title of the product in the description as H1 that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an answer,i don't know if its right but it does what i wanted it to do.

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET description = if(description is NULL, name, concat(name, description));";
```